# Joining four MySQL queries with same columns, different conditions

Tags: mysql, left-join, alias, where-clause

I have four queries that have 6 columns each. Each query is the same except for the WHERE clause is slightly different in each case. What I would like to see is each queries result for each column next to eachother for comparison.

Example result table headers: time(only one), calls1, calls2, calls3, calls4, work1, work2, work3, work4, tele1, tele2, tele3, tele4, comm1, comm2, comm3, comm4, techs1, techs2,techs3, techs4.

The actual queries are below. Please help me make a comparative query. T

```
SELECT CONCAT(hour(opened_dt),':',floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)*15) AS time, COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)) AS r_calls, ROUND(AVG(work_time),2)/60 AS r_work, ROUND(AVG(tele_time),2)/60 AS r_tele, ROUND(AVG(comm_time),2)/60 AS r_comm, IFNULL(COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)),0)/3 AS r_techs 
FROM detail_head LEFT JOIN detail_detail ON detail_detail.detail_head_uid = detail_head.detail_head_uid 
WHERE call_origins_uid != 5 
AND DATE(opened_dt) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY) 
AND dayname(opened_dt) = 'SUNDAY' 
GROUP BY (hour(opened_dt)*100)+floor(minute(opened_dt)/15) 


SELECT CONCAT(hour(opened_dt),':',floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)*15) AS time, COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)) AS calls, ROUND(AVG(work_time),2)/60 AS work, ROUND(AVG(tele_time),2)/60 AS tele, ROUND(AVG(comm_time),2)/60 AS comm, IFNULL(COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)),0)/3 AS techs 
FROM detail_head LEFT JOIN detail_detail ON detail_detail.detail_head_uid = detail_head.detail_head_uid 
WHERE call_origins_uid != 5 
AND DATE(opened_dt) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY) 
AND dayname(opened_dt) = 'SUNDAY' 
AND call_origins_uid = 1 
GROUP BY (hour(opened_dt)*100)+floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)


SELECT CONCAT(hour(opened_dt),':',floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)*15) AS time, COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)) AS calls, ROUND(AVG(work_time),2)/60 AS work, ROUND(AVG(tele_time),2)/60 AS tele, ROUND(AVG(comm_time),2)/60 AS comm, IFNULL(COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)),0)/3 AS techs 
FROM detail_head LEFT JOIN detail_detail ON detail_detail.detail_head_uid = detail_head.detail_head_uid 
WHERE call_origins_uid != 5 
AND DATE(opened_dt) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY) 
AND dayname(opened_dt) = 'SUNDAY' 
AND call_origins_uid = 4 
GROUP BY (hour(opened_dt)*100)+floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)


SELECT CONCAT(hour(opened_dt),':',floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)*15) AS time, COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)) AS calls, ROUND(AVG(work_time),2)/60 AS work, ROUND(AVG(tele_time),2)/60 AS tele, ROUND(AVG(comm_time),2)/60 AS comm, IFNULL(COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(opened_dt)),0)/3 AS techs 
FROM detail_head LEFT JOIN detail_detail ON detail_detail.detail_head_uid = detail_head.detail_head_uid 
WHERE DATE(opened_dt) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY) 
AND dayname(opened_dt) = 'SUNDAY' 
GROUP BY (hour(opened_dt)*100)+floor(minute(opened_dt)/15)
```

Comment: You need to format your queries for someone to help you. It's very taxing on the eyes :/

Comment: Updated the queries to make them easier to read. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TableName1' for each table then write a query to put the columns in order then drop the tables when your done.

Comment: Could you please explain? I haven't used temporary tables before.

Comment: Sure, other than the keyword 'temporary' the syntax for creating a table is the same as a normal table. The difference is the table only exists for the current connection. Another option would be to use your queries to create views and then query the views.

Comment: Could you give me an example? views?

Comment: For each of your queries you do one of the following. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table1 AS ('YOUR QUERY HERE'); or CREATE VIEW ViewName AS 'YOUR QUERY HERE'; The you could query either to get the desired formatting you want.

Comment: Or give me an example of a temporary table - I did some googling - but don't see a way to make this work for me...

Comment: I see what you're saying - I don't think this will work though... I'm wanting to see fields from each table next to eachother, followed by more fields from each table next to eachother - reference the example output above.

Comment: I completely gave up on this - I tried several things, but nothing seemed to work. You can get the 'right answer' simply for being the only person who TRIED. Cheers!

Comment: was traveling but was thinking you'd need something like this, it will return all the columns. Basically you're making an outer join in order to include all the columns from all the tables/views/queries. It's messy but it's the best I can come up with: select v1.*, v2.*
from v1 left join v2 v2 on v1.id = v2.id
right join v2 vv2 on v1.id = vv2.id;